# save gnome-terminal tabs configuration

Tags: gnome-terminal

How can I launch gnome-termninal with 4 tabs rooted at the same directory with each having a distinct tab-title and command launched at startup.

(one is the actual "shell", three others are tail -F on log-files)

I'd like to have a launcher in my menu to get that with a single click when I start working.

Comment: I am playing aroung with GNU screen now. seems to solve my problems, but I leve the question open, for hard-core gnome-terminal users ...

Answer (score 0):

You could launch it like this:

```
gnome-terminal --working-directory=/home/me/test --tab --title=ONE --tab --title=TWO --command='tail -F logfile_01' --tab --title=THREE --command='tail -F logfile_02' --tab --title=FOUR --command='tail -F logfile_03'
```